# The Centralizer $C_H(x)$ where $x \in G$ and $H \leq G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $x \in G$. Then

$C_H(x)=H$ if and only if $x \in Z(H)$?

It is obvious that if $x \in Z(H)$ then $C_H(x) = H$.

But I could not prove or provide a counter-example to the other statement.

Remark: $C_H(x) = \{h\in H | \ [h,x]=1\}$

Comment: If H is a subgroup of Z(G) then CH(x) = H but x need not be in Z(H)

Comment: I'm sorry, why does $G$ matter?

Comment: Because x is in G, not necessarily H.

Comment: how is $C_H(x)$ defined if $x$ is not in $H$?

Comment: The way it says in the question. The set of elements in H that commute with x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example of $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \{0\}$. Then $(0,1)$ satisfies $C_H((0,1))=H$, however $(0,1)\notin Z(H)$ because $(0,1)\notin H$.

Comment: Tanks for the suggestions and the answer.

Comment: @Eidu You're welcome.